# How to do timeout and then clear timeout in react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, functional-programming, timeout

#### Hi,

I have functional component in reactjs, and I am trying to do timeout on mouse hover over menu, which is fine and work well, but I dont know how to clear this timeout in other function in this same functional component, is there some solution for this? I primary use hooks. I found some hooks timeout, but not work well.
Thanks very much

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: its just functional component, where I catch onMouseEnter, and there I need to call timeout, which I need terminate (clearTimeout) in another function (onMouseLeave). I just need see how to work with timeout/cleartimeout in functional component / or with hooks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const Menu = () => {
  const timerRef = useRef(null);

  const onMouseEnter = () => {
    timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
  }

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    if(timerRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    }
  }

  return <div onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave} />
}
```

What's happening here is that, we are saving the timer's reference in a react ref. This can then be used to check and clear the timer in another function.